# Russian unicode to symbol using Query in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

[image]

I am trying to convert unicode to RUSSIAN CURRENCY  (руб) symbol in teradata. 
 Please find below query I have written but it is not converting unicode to symbol
 `sel translate('U+0431' UNICODE_TO_LATIN)`.
 I am getting output as unicode which has written in sql query **`U+0431`** but not desired symbol

Comment: You must either use a Unicode literal, but the UESCAP is mandatory: `U&'#0431' uescape '#'` or a Unicode hex literal: `_Unicode '0431'XC`

Comment: Also use CHARACTER SET UNICODE column and UTF8 or UTF16 session character set. This character does not exist in server LATIN ./ session ASCII.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. It worked